# Not able to get keys from JSON API hit in Table using React and axios.get function

Tags: reactjs, axios, material-ui

```
I have jsonAPI like this-----

{"result":
{"metaData":
[
{"name":"x"},
{"name":"y"},
{"name":"z"}
],
"rows":
[
["2012-12-06 11:15:12.440136","02","BFR85"],
["2011-12-04 10:15:14.756832","02","BRFU85"],
["2009-12-08 11:22:32.470736","03","UNHAT85]
]}}
```

I want to use this JSONAPI to display the data in the Table using react js:
This is how I am displaying data from JSONAPI using axios.get

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';


class Table extends React.Component {
  state = { something: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('in component mount for, ');    
      return axios.get('APIURL')
      .then(res => {     
        const something= res.data.result.rows;        
        this.setState({ something});       
      }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
  render(){ 

  return (   
    <Paper >
     <Table aria-labelledby="DATA">
        <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="center">INDEX</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">DataValue</TableCell>                 
          </TableRow>       
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>        
          {this.state.something.map((rows,i) => (
            <TableRow key={i}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {i}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>{this.state.something[i]}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>

      </Table>
    </Paper>
  );
}
}

export default Table;
```

Expected Result is shown below in the table---

```
    x     2012-12-06 11:15:12.440136","02","BFR85"
    y     2011-12-04 10:15:14.756832","02","BRFU85"
    z     2009-12-08 11:22:32.470736","03","UNHAT85"
```

Actual Result showing in the UI table is shown below:---

```
    1     2012-12-06 11:15:12.440136","02","BFR85"
    2     2011-12-04 10:15:14.756832","02","BRFU85"
    3     2009-12-08 11:22:32.470736","03","UNHAT85"
```

Please help on this issue to get the expected result ....

Comment: `this.state.something.map((rows,i)` **i** gives you i**ndex** of the current element in array, hence `{i}` shows `1,2,3` in result. You also should store `metadata` from json and access them with their **index**

Comment: Problem is that just like--const something= res.data.result.rows;  I am not able to get const somethingelse= res.data.result.metadata;

Comment: key in JSON is `metaData` and not `metadata` if you have not written by mistake

Comment: the length of the `metaData` is matched with the length of the `Rows`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  state = { 
    something: [], 
    keyValues: [],
};

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('in component mount for, ');    
      return axios.get('APIURL')
      .then(res => {     
        const something= res.data.result.rows; 
        const keyValues = res.data.result.metaData;       
        this.setState({ something, keyValues});       
      }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
  render(){ 

  return (   
    <Paper >
     <Table aria-labelledby="DATA">
        <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="center">INDEX</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">DataValue</TableCell>                 
          </TableRow>       
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>        
          {this.state.something.map((rows,i) => (
            <TableRow key={i}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {this.state.keyValues[i].name}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>{this.state.something[i]}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>

      </Table>
    </Paper>
  );
}
}

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try blow code.

```
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {this.state.keyValues[i].name}
              </TableCell>
```